# Instancing an object and calling a method in one line?

Tags: c#

I have a lot of code like this

```
var o = new SomeClass().DoSomething(someParam);
```

Is this a design flaw ?

This class is some kind of a builder class.It should contruct other object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the instance after calling the method, you probably better with a static method on `SomeClass` and ends up with

```
var o = SomeClass.DoSomething(someParam);
```

and if for any reason, you absolutely need a new instance to execute `DoSomething` then you could create a static factory method to make the code more readable like :

```
var o = SomeClass.GetInstance().DoSomething(someParam)
```

Answer (score 10):

Nope, that's fine - and in particular you might see it frequently with types which are used as builders. For example:

```
string x = new StringBuilder().Append("Foo")
                              .AppendFormat("{0}:{1}", x, y)
                              .ToString();
```

Or in my Protocol Buffers port:

```
Person p = new Person.Builder { Name = "Jon", Age = 35 }.Build();
```

Here the `Person` type is immutable, but the *builder* type isn't - so you create a builder, set some properties, and then call `Build`.

Comment: Really helpful to a learner 10 decades later

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem in terms of style.
This will be a problem if you need the constructed SomeClass after invoking the DoSomething method.

Answer (score 1):

It's not flawed design. I'd say that the only problem is readability, if the rest of your team is not using this style then don't use it especially with **var** cause it makes it harder to understand what is returned. For me, I personally like it since I am used to chaining from jquery.